# In R targets, cannot read target object of class "dataset"

Tags: r, torch, targets-r-package

I am struggling with interoperability of R packages **torch** and **targets**.  For example, if I define a target of class `dataset` (from **torch**), then it is impossible to read it with `tar_read` (from **targets**), and I cannot use it in other targets.

Here is my `dataset` generator `nn_dataset`:

```r
library(torch)
library(targets)
library(dplyr)
library(tidymodels)

nn_dataset <- 
  dataset(
    name = "nn_dataset",
    
    initialize = function(df) {
      data <- self$prepare_data(df)
      
      self$tele <- data$x$tele
      self$class <- data$x$class
      self$y <- data$y
    },
    
    .getitem = function(i) {
      list(
        x = list(
          tele = self$tele[i, ], 
          class = self$class[i, ]
        ), 
        y = self$y[i, ]
      )
    },
    
    .length = function() {
      self$y$size()[[1]]
    },
    
    prepare_data = function(df) {
      target_col <- 
        df$claim_ind_cov_1_2_3_4_5_6 %>% 
        as.integer() %>%
        `-`(1) %>%
        as.matrix()
      
      tele_cols <- 
        df %>%
        select(starts_with(c("h_", "p_", "vmo", "vma"))) %>%
        as.matrix()
    
      class_df <- select(df, expo:years_licensed, distance)
      
      rec_class <-
        recipe(~ ., data = class_df) %>%
        step_impute_median(commute_distance, years_claim_free) %>%
        step_other(all_nominal(), threshold = 0.05) %>%
        step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
        prep()

      class_cols <- juice(rec_class) %>% as.matrix()
      
      list(
        x = list(
          tele = torch_tensor(tele_cols),
          class = torch_tensor(class_cols)
        ),
        y = torch_tensor(target_col)
      )
    }
)
```

If I define the following target:

```r
tar_target(
  name = target_name,
  command = nn_dataset(valid_df)
)
```

where `valid_df` is a tibble, and if I then try to read it:

```r
tar_read(target_name)
```

then I get this error:

```
Error in cpp_tensor_dim(self$ptr) : external pointer is not valid
```

I have also tried this:

```r
tar_target(
  name = target_name,
  command = nn_dataset(valid_df),
  format = "torch"  
)
```

and this:

```r
tar_torch(
  name = target_name,
  command = nn_dataset(valid_df)
)
```

but neither worked.

Comment: `format = "torch"` or `format = tar_format(...)` is definitely recommended for torch objects because of those external pointers. `targets` tries to save and load objects, and torch tensors are not exportable: https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html. Not sure why it's erroring out when you include `format = "torch"`, and I cannot run your code because it has datasets that I do not have. Please have a look at https://books.ropensci.org/targets/help.html, especially the section on reprexes.

Comment: Hello @landau. Thank you very much for your help and for your time! I managed to reproduce the bug with a reprex that you can find at this URL:

https://github.com/francisduval/reprex_targets_torch_bug

To restore the library from the lockfile, please run renv::restore() (I'm sure you know that :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format = "torch"` capability of `targets` relies on `torch::torch_save()` and `torch::torch_load()`, and these functions in `torch` do not work on the custom `R6` classes that come out of `MyDataset(mtcars)` in your example. On top of that, `torch` data is "non-exportable", and as discussed at https://books.ropensci.org/targets/targets.html#saving and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html, that data cannot simply be saved to disk with something like `saveRDS()` (which is the default in `targets`). I do not know `torch` well enough to recommend something specific, but a solution would require figuring out the R code that will safely save and load one of these objects, then creating your own custom storage format using [`tar_format()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/reference/tar_format.html). The code at https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/reference/tar_format.html#ref-examples has an example for Keras models.

A better alternative would actually be to avoid saving R6 objects altogether because those are really pieces of code that [do not hash well](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/345). If you can restructure the pipeline to save simpler versions of the data and only re-create those `R6` classes on an as-needed basis, that would be much better, especially if those `R6` classes take no time at all to create from e.g. a data frame. So you first target could be the `mtcars` data frame, and then the model-fitting target could call `MyDataset(mtcars)`, fit the model, and return easy-to-save output generated from that fitted model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really addresses my issue. Moreover, it helped me understand the targets package a little better. Cheers!

Comment: My plan is to avoid saving R6 objects and re-create them on an as-needed basis instead, as recommended. I found that the way to save a trained neural network, i.e. an object of class luz_module_fitted, is with the luz::luz_save function. I will therefore create my own custom format based on that with targets::tar_format. The trained neural network is really the most important thing to save for me since it takes time to run.